# share self instance between python scripts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The problem I am having now is the user inputs are being called twice. Is there any better way to share self between python scripts more easily and avoid calling input twice. I read about multiprocessing module in python, but couldn't use it.
This is a short example:

**script1.py:**

```
class importparam(object):

  def dataset1(self):
      self.var1=1
      self.var2=2
      self.var3=3
      self.var4=input('enter var4 : ')


  def dataset2(self):
      self.const1=11
      self.const2=22
      self.const3=33
      self.const4 = input('enter const4 : ')
```

**script2.py:**

```
from main import main_
class reader_(main_):

    def __init__(self):
        super(reader_, self).__init__()

    def addition(self):
        self.add1 = self.const1+self.const2
        self.add2 = self.const3+self.const4

    def multiply(self):
        self.mult1 = self.var1+self.var2
        self.mult2 = self.var3+self.var4
```

**main.py**

```
from script1 import importparam

class main_(importparam):

    def __init__(self):

        super(main_, self).dataset1()
        super(main_, self).dataset2()

    def fun1(self):

        from script2 import reader_

        r=reader_()
        val=1
        if val==1:
            r.addition()
        else:
            r.multiply()



if __name__=='__main__':
    main_().fun1()
```

Comment: Your program structure is overcomplicated, with circular dependencies (`main` depends on `script2` but `script2` depends on `main`) so it would benefit from redesign.

Comment: BTW, your issue is not "sharing" `self` between scripts. You create one instance of `main` and one instance of `reader_` (which itself is instance of `main`, so you have two instances of `main` total. That's why you get prompted for input twice.